# npm run build failed bitbucket pipleline

Tags: reactjs, pipeline, bitbucket-pipelines, autodeploy

I have below error

```
+ REACT_APP_STAGE=qa npm run build
> EcoBux@0.1.0 build /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build
> react-scripts build
Creating an optimized production build...
Treating warnings as errors because process.env.CI = true.
Most CI servers set it automatically.
Failed to compile.
./src/component/login/GLogin.js
  Line 10:12:  'details' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars
./src/component/HowWeWork.js
  Line 16:29:  <iframe> elements must have a unique title property                                                                           jsx-a11y/iframe-has-title
  Line 31:72:  Using target="_blank" without rel="noopener noreferrer" is a security risk: see https://mathiasbynens.github.io/rel-noopener  react/jsx-no-target-blank
  Line 34:66:  Using target="_blank" without rel="noopener noreferrer" is a security risk: see https://mathiasbynens.github.io/rel-noopener  react/jsx-no-target-blank
./src/component/login/FbLogin.js
  Line 1:17:   'useEffect' is defined but never used         no-unused-vars
  Line 12:12:  'details' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars
./src/layout/ContentArea.js
  Line 1:17:  'useContext' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars
./src/component/map/LeaftLetMap.js
  Line 1:17:  'useState' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars
  Line 3:33:  'Circle' is defined but never used    no-unused-vars
./src/component/Buy.js
  Line 2:8:    'DollarImg' is defined but never used                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             no-unused-vars
  Line 10:20:  'error' is assigned a value but never used                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        no-unused-vars
  Line 23:25:  The href attribute requires a valid value to be accessible. Provide a valid, navigable address as the href value. If you cannot provide a valid href, but still need the element to resemble a link, use a button and change it with appropriate styles. Learn more: https://github.com/evcohen/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/blob/master/docs/rules/anchor-is-valid.md  jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid
./src/App.js
  Line 2:8:   'logo' is defined but never used         no-unused-vars
  Line 3:43:  'Redirect' is defined but never used     no-unused-vars
  Line 7:8:   '$' is defined but never used            no-unused-vars
  Line 8:8:   'Popper' is defined but never used       no-unused-vars
  Line 15:8:  'LeaftLetMap' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars
./src/utils/sessionDetails.js
  Line 2:8:  'moment' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars
./src/utils/LoadScript.js
  Line 2:8:  'moment' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars
./src/layout/Header.js
  Line 38:10:   React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'pTitle'. Either include it or remove the dependency array                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  Line 59:69:   The href attribute requires a valid value to be accessible. Provide a valid, navigable address as the href value. If you cannot provide a valid href, but still need the element to resemble a link, use a button and change it with appropriate styles. Learn more: https://github.com/evcohen/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/blob/master/docs/rules/anchor-is-valid.md  jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid
  Line 59:112:  Script URL is a form of eval                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      no-script-url
./src/component/paypal/Paypal.js
  Line 8:19:   'setError' is assigned a value but never used                                                                                                                                                                                                               no-unused-vars
  Line 44:10:  React Hook React.useEffect has missing dependencies: 'amount' and 'setCheckout'. Either include them or remove the dependency array. If 'setCheckout' changes too often, find the parent component that defines it and wrap that definition in useCallback  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
./src/component/Home.js
  Line 8:8:    'HomefbIocn' is defined but never used               no-unused-vars
  Line 9:8:    'HomeTwitterIcon' is defined but never used          no-unused-vars
  Line 63:41:  <iframe> elements must have a unique title property  jsx-a11y/iframe-has-title
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! EcoBux@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the EcoBux@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-09-02T07_20_23_624Z-debug.log
```

I can see there is only warning kind of messages...

Does warning failed the build  in pipeline as its working locally. or I am missing something else, also I could not find the way to see the complete log file

Please help
Thanks

Comment: Log is saying: Treating warnings as errors because process.env.CI = true. Have you tried to fix the warning or setting it to false?

Comment: Could you please let me know how to set in false, should I put this process.env.CI = true in package .json

Comment: Yes I tried CI=''  and it passed .. Thanks alot... could you please let me know how to see complete log

Comment: You need to log into the server which is executing the build and go under /root/.npm/_logs/2020-09-02T07_20_23_624Z-debug.log. A SSH connection should be enough